# How to connect to an oracle database securely ? How to avoid clear text passwords?

Tags: php, oracle, connection

I am developing a php application but my password is in clear text when I connect to my oracle database.
Is there a solution to avoid this?

```sql
$login = '..';
$password = '..';
$db= '..';
$conn= oci_connect($login, $password, $db);
if ($conn) {
        echo "Connected";
}
 else { 
    trigger_error(htmlentities(oci_error()['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

The answer I found for now is to call an external file :
External file (configDatabase.php) :

```php
<?php
// All connections to the database use these credentials
define("ORA_CON_UN", "..");
define("ORA_CON_PW", "..");
define("ORA_CON_DB", "..");
?>
```

Login.php :

```php
<?php

// login.php

require_once('../configDatabase.php');
```

Comment: This is not what "clear text" generally means. This term is usually used when the password is _transmitted_ in clear text over the network, which is not what is happening. That said, as you have gathered, it is best practice to keep passwords out of source code files, and especially out of source control systems. The usual solution here is to use uncommitted configuration files (like INI or YAML) and/or environment variables.

Comment: Use an Oracle wallet